# CustomValidator, pagemethods and JQuery what fun

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

I have a CustomValidator, RequiredFieldValidator and ValidationSummary controls on an aspx page to check the current password and make sure the new password is not blank.

When I click submit I get the js alert() box from the summary control telling me about just the RequiredFieldValidator being false, but the client script for the CustomValidator does not seem to get its return value used. I have checked the "arguments.IsValid" value using FireBug, so it is getting called and returning the correct bool, but it never shows up in the val summary box?

Thanks,
Goosey

Comment: Can you post the client script for the Custom Validator?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say what is going on without the code.  As a side note, you might want to check out the [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/) framework as I think it handles what you are looking to do.